# "does not name type" error when using EtherTen and Arduino

Tags: twitter, arduino

I am currently using an [EtherTen](http://www.freetronics.com/products/etherten) to try and connect Arduino to [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter). However, I keep getting an error saying "'twitter'does not name a type". How can I fix this problem?

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO > 18   // Arduino 0019 or later
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetDNS.h>  //Only needed in Arduino 0022 or earlier
#include <Twitter.h>

byte MACaddress[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte IPaddress[] = { 10, 0, 0, 177 };
Twitter twitter("MY TOKEN HERE");
char msg[] = "Hello, World! I'm Arduino!";

void setup()
{
    delay(1000);
    Ethernet.begin(MACaddress, IPaddress);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("connecting ...");
    if (twitter.post(msg)) {
        int status = twitter.wait();
        if (status == 200) {
            Serial.println("OK.");
        }
        else {
            Serial.print("failed : code ");
            Serial.println(status);
        }
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("connection failed.");
    }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Are there no other errors, such as not being able to open Twitter.h?

Comment: can you give all the errors you're getting when compiling? The complete log

Comment: are you sure the `Twitter/Twitter.h` is in your compilation path? somewhere like in `Document/Arduino/Libraries`

Comment: and are you using an old version of Arduino app? you're posting a code that is for old version 0022, whereas we've past 1.0 a long time ago. You may also want to take an example from a recent version of both twitter lib and arduino!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fair question. It looks a lot like the sample code. The first thing I would try is removing the "<<<" and the ">>>" from the constructor?

```
    Twitter twitter("1521141456-FjH4fHVENG3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

If that does not help you could look at your Ethernet.begin .

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
```

rather than

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
```

NOTE 
You should be careful posting your twitter token id on a forum. I think you should edit your post so as to hide your token.

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice!! Unfortunately neither of these suggestions worked, do you have any other ideas of what could be causing this error?